# UIScrollView w/ Large CATiledLayer + Overlay that renders fast

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, catiledlayer

I've been working on something for weeks now (iOS) and I can't seem to figure out an acceptable solution.

Requirements

- Display a 10000x10000 pixel background image
- Zooming and scrolling responsive
- Overlay on top that has custom drawing
- Elements in overlay are interactive (tapping and highlighting elements, etc) and pieces can be turned on or off.
- iOS 4.0

Think of it as a geographic map of a fictional town, with a crazy system of roads, lines, areas and buildings drawn on top. A mixture of CGPaths with fills of various opacities, some icon images etc. It's like a more complicated version of google maps app.

What i've tried:

---

**1 - Multiple CATiled Layers**

View Hierarchy:

- ScrollView
- ->ContainerView
- -->TiledView (CATiledLayer 10000x10000)
- --->OverlayView (CATiledLayer 10000x10000)

Results:
Drops tiles from magic apple cache left and right. Two CATiledlayers doesn't seem to be the right path. Updates to overlay aren't fast.

---

**2 - Subclass TiledView for OverlayView**

View Hierarchy:

- ScrollView
- ->OverlayView (Subclass of TiledView CATiledLayer 10000x10000)

Results:
Takes way too long to render updates for the overlay. 
Slow to update tiles

---

**3 - Scrollview w/ a single container view**

View Hierarchy:

- ScrollView
- ->ContainerView (10000x10000)
- -->OverlayView (CALayer 10000x10000)
- -->TiledView (CATiledLayer 10000x10000)

Results:
Fails to work because OverlayView consumes too much memory. TileView is fine because it is backed by CATiledLayer

---

**4 - OverlayView that uses scroll delegate and CTM scale/translate to simulate being large**

View Hierarchy:

- OverlayView (CALayer 1024x768)
- ScrollView
- ->TiledView (CATiledLayer 10000x10000)

Results:
I use the scrollview delegates to adjust the offset and zoom of the overlay view. The problem with this method is that drawrect is called like 100 times a second and the overlay view can't draw fast enough so it's completely lagged down to 1fps.

---

So that's where I am at. I feel this last method is on to something, but would require some crazy work to tame the drawrect madness. Other thoughts would be to try to tackle something in OpenGL.

Before I go about doing those I'd thought I'd ask the community to see what they would do/have done facing similar requirements.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestions is to have two views in your scrollview. The background CATiledLayer view. The second view is a custom UIView that sits above the background view - this is where you do your custom drawing. The custom view should have a drawRect: method that for now does nothing.

So you try this with nothing in your customView, and make sure scrolling etc is as you want it. If the problem is in the background view and you need to resolve that.

At that point, your custom view starts drawing stuff. Note that you will get a rect to update in drawRect. Perhaps you have a thousand items that might need drawing over the whole canvas - so each has a frame property, so you can determine given current zoom and frame what needs to be drawn. You only draw those items.

This general technique has worked well in the past for me.

EDIT2:

So running on a device, I duplicated the "cannot allocate" messages. So plan B. What you can do is have a container view, which has two views - the scroll view and a new UIView subclass. The scrollView has the huge monster view. The subclass view has a frame that is exactly the UIScrollView frame.

You would then make sure that you get the scrollView messages "scrollViewDidScroll:", and probably others.

When the scrollView is stable, or you et the above message, then the the custom UIView subclass gets a message that says draw but using an offset which is the scrollView contentOffset.

The work the custom class has to do is the same. Instead of using its drawRect origin point, it takes that point and offsets it by the contentOffset of the scrollView. Now, when you draw, you are looking for objects that are in scope of the point passed in the drawRect:rect offset positively by the scrollview offset.

Comment: I basically tried that in example 3. I get the CoreAnimation can't allocate 15000000 bytes error (which I thought is the direct result of a 10000x10000 pt view being added to the window without a catiledlayer backing). Are you suggesting that I shouldn't be getting that error?

Comment: Well, lets walk though this. first, just the background layer is working (I assume yets) So if you create a UIView subclass, add a drawRect: method (got to do this, just don't do anything yet), and add that to the scrollView too, that fails? Just want to make sure of this - with the drawRect I **believe** the system won't try to make a backing layer. [I suggested a similar solution so someone else a month or so ago, its seems to be working...]

Comment: I just created a new UIView subclass that simply overrides drawrect with empty implementation. I initialized the view with a CGRectMake(0,0,10000,10000) and then added it to the scrollview along with my background "TiledView". Still get the CoreAnimation allocation error :\

Comment: Uh, MyCustomView *view = [MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGrectmake....]; - that's what you did? Well, I was hoping that would work...but if not, plan B.

Comment: Been going at this non-stop.... but to your edit1 yes, but when you have the drawrect like that on a monster view it blows up on device. now for edit2 I believe that's the same as what i have in my 4th method above. 
Unless i'm not understanding you right, the problem is if the scrollViewDidScroll method calls setNeedsDisplay on the overlay view, it gets spammed a ridiculous amount of drawrect calls and pretty much slows the device down to a screeching halt.

Comment: My point is, this is your only option. So you need to manage how its done. Note that the drawrect sent by the system only has the area needing updating. You can keep track of how fast the scrollView is moving, and if fast, then suppress drawing at all (or used some canned spinner image). The idea is to really draw when you need to, when things are moving fast figure out something else to do so as to not cause too much delay. Really, if user is really nagivating far away, they dont need pixel perfect views shown for a few milliseconds.

Comment: Interesting approach - did anybody get *Plan B* to work (smoothly)..?

Comment: @Jay I didn't pursue it. Note that the original questioner didn't even upvote my answer (and I do appreciate that you did!). You might want to add a comment to the original question to see if the author figured something out.

Answer (score 1):

I drawed a path-based map once, but i did not have a background image, only paths. I used only one View with drawrect (no Scrollview) and implemented the scrolling/zooming by myself. There where some performance issues, especially on ipad3 with highresolution as it has problems with allocating a full resolution imagecontext.

- do not use shadows etc. on a Path, this will kill your performance.
- precalculate all bounding-boxes of your Paths/objects and store them in some order so you can lookup  the visible paths/objects as fast as possible.
- use different-detailed pathsets for different zoomlevels.

but at the end i think openGL is the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for everybody struggling with this as well. You should use two Tiled Views which are zoomed/scrolled in the same way, but the overlay view should NOT be a subview of the background view. That is, you should have:

- ScrollView
- ->ContainerView
- -->TiledView (CATiledLayer 10000x10000)
- -->OverlayView (CATiledLayer 10000x10000)

Then for drawing speed, it really comes down to how you do the drawing for the overlay. For each tile, you should make sure that you only draw that which overlays the tile, not all the other stuff that falls outside the boundary of the tile.