# UIScrollView - using zoomscale and contentsoffset for CGAffineTransform

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, cgaffinetransform

Some background on this-> I'm using a UIScrollview (holding a 10,000x10,000 catiledlayer backed view) and passing it's delegate to a custom overlay view (that is the size of the screen) that will be scaled and moved around depending on the zoom and content offset of the view.

I'm struggling with taming the contentoffset/zoomscale from the didScroll: didZoom: delegates into a CGAffineTransform I can apply to my "overlay" view.  Scrolling is pretty straightforward as it's a simple translate. Zooming seems to be the challenge because I have to combine with the current translate as well.  Once scrolling/zooming 
stops I clear the transforms and redraw view (which is the easy part).

(previous question [UIScrollView w/ Large CATiledLayer + Overlay that renders fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150609/uiscrollview-w-large-catiledlayer-overlay-that-renders-fast) about best methods for doing this)

So my question: How can i convert the contentoffset & zoomscale into a cgaffinetransform i can apply to another view in order to make it appear that i am pinching/zooming/scrolling the overlay view?

Comment: there is a WWDC video regarding CATiledLayer few years back, maybe worth revisiting if you havnt already done so, good luck!

Comment: ..all the search turns up is **WWDC 2011/104**: **Advanced ScrollView Techniques**, which is about _not_ using `CATiledLayer`.. anybody else got another WWDC session suggestion?